# CSS - Background Image With a fixed Div

Tags: html, css

I've started with this code. Results as expected, I have a image as the background of my first div, and it takes up the whole space.

```
<div id="Page1"></div>

<style>
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("/someImageLink");
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
</style
```

Every thing is fine, now I want to add...

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

...in the css. Now the background image disappears all the way.

Is it possible to use a `<img>` to do the same thing as css background-image, or make it clip without it going blank?

Additional Information: I want a few of these divs in a row.They will appear and disappear as needed.

There will be buttons and text within the divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div does not have a width. It is necessary to add one now that you have changed its `position` from `static` to `fixed`